# ODBC driver wont connect with my SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, connection, odbc, driver

I'm building a database driven app in C# and when I run the program I get the following error:

> The connection with the ODBC Driver for SQLNameofMyPC/SQLSERVER2019
> has failed.

Note that:

I don't know why I get this error only when I run a particular form which is connected with the access database and not with the SQL SERVER.Τhe other two first forms are connected with the SQL server database but I wont get this error when I run those two forms.

Comment: Does the actual error message have a forward slash `/` as mentioned in `SQLNameofMyPC/SQLSERVER2019`? Instance Names are meant to be delimited using backslash characters, e.g.: `SQLNameofMyPC\SQLSERVER2019`

Comment: yes the slash is like this  \ and not like this /. Sorry my mistake